# Jenkins Multibranch-Pipeline JobDSL can't specify github url

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl, multibranch-pipeline

I'm creating a Multibranch Pipeline job with JobDSL , and I want to specify my github url , but it's not working.

The job which I created it display "https://**github.com**/jackson/multibranch-Pipeline.git" ,

not https://**mycompanygithub.com**/jackson/multibranch-Pipeline.git

Any idea how theses other parameters can be added in ?

or other solution

```
multibranchPipelineJob('Jenkins/Multibranch-Pipeline/GitHub_Basic') {
    branchSources {
        branchSource {
            source {
                github {
                    repositoryUrl('https://mycompanygithub.com')
                    credentialsId('mycredentialsid')
                    repoOwner('jackson')
                    repository('multibranch-Pipeline.git')
                    configuredByUrl(true)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your configuration is correct, your are just missing one parameter: `apiUri`

> // The server to connect to.
> apiUri(String value)

Without it, it takes the default github.com as the base domain for the repository regardless of what is configured in the `repositoryUrl` parameter.
Try the following:

```
multibranchPipelineJob('Jenkins/Multibranch-Pipeline/GitHub_Basic') {
   branchSources {
       branchSource {
           source {
               github {
                   apiUri('https://mycompanygithub.com/api/v3')
                   repositoryUrl('https://mycompanygithub.com')
                   credentialsId('mycredentialsid')
                   repoOwner('jackson')
                   repository('multibranch-Pipeline.git')
                   configuredByUrl(true)
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

By the way you can see the full documentation of the Job DSL of this plugin at the following URL on your own Jenkins server:
*YOUR_JENKINS_URL/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.DslFactory.multibranchPipelineJob*